# Radon measure with support in a set

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a Radon measure with support contained in a set $D \subset \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. If $f = 0$ a.e. in $D$, does it follow that
$$\int_\Omega f\;\mathrm{d}\mu = 0?$$
Could someone explain me the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not follow if a.e. is related to Lebesgue's measure. Consider $\Omega = (0,1)$, $D = \{1/2\}$, $\mu = \delta_{1/2}$ is a Dirac and $f = 1$. Then, $D$ has Lebesgue measure zero, hence $f = 0$ a.e. on $D$ but $\int_\Omega f \,\mathrm{d}\mu = 1$.

Comment: thank you. any idea if quasi-everywhere would be better?

Comment: In one dimension, yes, since it implies everywhere. In more than one dimension, a single point has zero capacity and, yet, it can support a Dirac measure.