# Is $\langle \mu, z \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1}=0$ if $\mu \in H^{-1}$ has support in a subdomain on which $z$ vanishes?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a positive Radon measure on a bounded domain $\Omega$ such that $\mu \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Furthermore, $\mu$ has support in $Z \subset \Omega$, which is a subdomain of $\Omega$.

Suppose I have a function $z \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $z=0$ a.e. in $Z$.

Is it enough to conclude that
$$\langle \mu, z \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1_0} = 0?$$

I just a saw thread ([Radon measure with support in a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291774/radon-measure-with-support-in-a-set)) related to this... but I think mine is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not enough. Your $\mu$ could be a $d-1$-dimensional measure on a hyperplane, e.g., a line measure in two dimensions. Then, the support $Z$ is the hyperplane, which has measure zero. Hence, all function vanish a.e. on this hyperplane.

Comment: But $Z$ is a subdomain (so measure is non-zero). Does it make a difference?

Comment: Do you mean that $Z$ is an open set?

Comment: i think it is closed. (in fact $Z=\{x : u(x) = \psi(x) \}$ is the coincidence set of an obstacle problem, which I know to be a non-null set).

Comment: No, this is not enough. In my example, $Z$ is a hyperplane, thus, it is closed. If you would know that $Z$ is open, then everything is fine. You might want to have a look at capacity theory: it would be enough to know $z = 0$ quasi-everywhere on $Z$.